# Is the maximum modulus of an entire function on a circle of radius $r$ a smooth function of $r$?

Tags: complex-analysis, smooth-functions

Let $f$ be a non-constant holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C},$ for any $r>0,$ set
$$M(r)=\max_{|z|=r}|f(z)|$$
Is $M(r)\in C^{\infty}(0,+\infty)$ ? I have showed that $M(r)$ is continuous and strictly increasing, but I have no idea to deal with the derivative of $M(r),$ can someone help me?

Comment: It is known that $M'(r)$ exists with the possible exception of a discrete sequence of points tending to $\infty$:  O. BLUMENTHAL: Sur le mode de croissance des fonctions entieres, Bulletin de la S. M. F., tome 35 (1907), p. 213-232. You can find the paper here http://www.numdam.org/item/10.24033/bsmf.808.pdf

Comment: Any monotonic function is differentiable ae and in this case it shouldn't be hard to show that the points of non differentiability are discrete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f(z)=(1-z)e^z$ then if $r\le 2$ we have $r=2\sin \theta/2$ for a unique $0\le \theta \le \pi$ and it is a good exercise to show that if $z_r=1-e^{i\theta}$ has modulus as above, $f$ attains maximum modulus at $z_r$ which gives $M(f,r)=e^{r^2/2}, r\le 2$; however if $r\ge 2$ it is not hard to show that $M(f,r)=(r-1)e^r$ obtained at $z=r$ so $M$ is not smooth at $2$.

Comment: A nice example! And motivated by your example, I wonder whether the conclusion can be modified to that $M(r)$ is smooth for $r$ sufficiently small enough?

Comment: I think that this is known (with small enough depending on $f$ of course) and actually that $M$ is real analytic near zero since wlog we can assume $f(0)=1$ (factoring $cz^k$ which change $M$ by $|c|r^k$) and then near $0$ we have that $f$ behaves like $1+az^k$; there is a very interesting (open) conjecture called Blumenthal conjecture per pare referenced above, which asks if $M$ determines $f$ uniquely up to obvious transforms